# How can you check when a uiview has appeared on screen/finished drawing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I seem to be having some problems with a drawrect method. I'm drawing a PDF page onto a view using CGContextDrawPDFPage and then I wish to run  UIView animation on the view's frame once it has loaded. However, if I call the animation at the end of the drawrect method, it causes a jerky animation because the animation is midway through its duration before the UIView actually appears on screen (sometimes 2 seconds later.

I'm looking for a way of checking whether the view has finished drawing. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated?

Here's my code...

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)inRect{  

pageRef = [[PDFManager sharedManager] getLargePDFPageRefForPage:pageNumber];
if(pageRef) {
    ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, [self bounds].size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, [self bounds], 0, true));
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationNone);
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pageRef);    
}

[self moveFrame];

}


-(void)moveFrame{


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 400);


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - `drawRect:` method is called each time when the view "gets dirty" which might be very often. My advice for you would be to write the "moving" code not in the view class, but in controller class, which is probably better place regarding the separation of concerns (controller manages the view's position while view manages the drawing of itself). The flow would be similar to this:

1. Initiate the view and add it as the subview (in the controller). This will cause the view to draw itself.
2. Move the actual view to the place you need it to be (in the controller).

Comment: I see where you're coming from but this does not fix the issue because the "add subview" is finished being called before even the draw rect method in the uiview. Nice thought though.

Comment: So when adding subview, mark it as dirty with `[subview setNeedsDisplay:YES]`. This should force call the `drawRect:` method.

Comment: The issue isn't that drawRect: isn't being called straight away, the issue is that is finishes but takes time to display the view. Therefore, I would like to know when the view has been rendered on screen.